# variable _ in lua has a special meaning?

Tags: variables, lua

I am a newbie to lua / torch. I notice that the variable _ is used a lot, especially in iterators. Example:

```
for _, node in ipairs(protos.rnn.forwardnodes) do
    a, b = whatever(a,b)
end
```

this 'variable naming convention' (so to speak) is used in other circumstances as well, as in:

```
local _,loss = optimizer(feval,params, optim_state)
```

Does _ have any special meaning or is it just one more variable name, among the many possible names?

Comment: Some IDEs will give you a warning if you declare a variable and don't use it, or assign it a new value without using the previous value. Respecting the conventional use of `_` as a throwaway variable, they obviously wouldn't do that for `_` even though it is just an ordinary variable.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's usually used as a throwaway variable. It has no "real" special meaning, but is used to signify that the indicated value is not important.

> The variable consisting of only an underscore "_" is commonly used as a placeholder when you want to ignore the variable...

Read more [here](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaStyleGuide) (under the *naming* portion).

Answer (score 17):

The use of _ is usually for **returning values you don't want from a function**. Which makes sense, it looks like a *blank*. The reason it's commonly used when iterating is because most iterators return key,value pairs, and you *only* need the value.

However, _ can also be used for the *exact* opposite. When placed behind a variable, such as `_G` or `_VERSION`, it signifies it is **important** and *shouldn't* be changed.

And finally, the double underscore. I've only ever used these for **metamethods**, such as `__index` or `__add`, so if you're making a function or API or whatever that checks for a custom metamethod, make sure to be consistent, and use a double underscore.

So in the end, it's just a naming convention, and is totally opinionated and optional.

Comment: I had more information than the other answer to offer up to the table, so I posted my own answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: it certainly does warspyking!

Comment: If I left anything out feel free to tell me, I'd love to make the answer more informative.